# Menu items wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this WordPress site, which has several pages (and some of them are standard to WooCommerce) I would like the menu not to contain the links to "check out" and "Cart" which should be available using the direct link, but not part of the menu. (I have an icon for the cart, which has a link to the cart, and from there you can go to checkout)

I am using a storefront theme, and have checked the "menus" field, and cart and checkout are not listed there.

Pictures can be added if needed.

All suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to create your own menu to see if the checkout out and cart button still persist?

Comment: By adding a your own menu, you mean by creating it within the "template modifier"? 
If so, yes I have..

Comment: You can remove menu items in Wordpress Appearance > Menus selecting the primary menu and removing undesired items from it…

Comment: This is what I have done, but I had to remove the entire menu and then add it again, which made it work as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the menu, and add everything again, this solved the issue.